# Allow the user to hide the "these are similar questions" pane and bring the formatting pane back

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-interface, asking-questions

The "How to Format" tool is extremely useful. However, now that the "similar questions" thing occupies both the huge area between the title and body, AND the entire sidebar, there's now no way to see the formatting help.

It would be awesome if there were something we could hover our mouse over to see the formatting help again. Things like images I never remember how to format right.

[image: HowToFormat Missing]

Comment: Can you elaborate why the *actual* formatting help doesn't do the job?

Comment: @balpha: What "actual" formatting help? The buttons on the top of the editor? I'd rather know what code to type rather than clicking on buttons.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/inline-comment-and-post-markdown-help/

Comment: @balpha: Discoverability fail. :P (+1 to comment)

Comment: +1 for being the second person I know who looks at that colored rounded box at the right (besides myself).

Comment: @BoltClock +2 for pointing that out, but I gave you half of that in a previous life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, just click the help icon instead.

[image]

It is more important to find duplicates than it is to re-create the built in editor help, once you've started composing the post.

Also note that for new users (100 or below rep) the editor help is pre-expanded anyway. Try it yourself in Google Chrome Incognito mode to see.